# How can I loop a range within find_element_by_xpath?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this error when trying to loop through the following range.

TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

```
for x in range(1, 12): 
addressxpath = '"table/tbody/tr[' + str(x) + ']/td/ul[1]/li[1]/div/a"'

address = driver.find_element_by_xpath(addressxpath)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you have double quotes embedded in the string?

Comment: Hi John. I need to have the quotations in seeing that it's a URL